# Please help me remember book about children and stones that possessed power

Tags: story-identification, books, childrens-novel

It's a children's book, there was a group of children (who I think were running away from a man) and these kids were able to 'listen' to stones.

And then there was this other child, a girl. She wasn't with the group of children but meet in the end. She was experimented on and she was able to use these stones.

Please help me remember! I really liked it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This could be the book you are looking for [*Stone Voice Rising*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6314931-stone-voice-rising) by C.Lee Tocci. I checked over at Amazon.com as it had been a few years since I had read it. The reviews there seem to fit your description and helped jog my memory a bit.

> Lilibit can hear what the stones are whispering. She is meant to be the earth’s new Stone Voice who will ultimately connect the planet with the universe. Her protector, a stone warrior, attempts to take her to the place called Kiva to fulfill her destiny--but they are intercepted by Syxx, an evil entity devoted to finding the source of Lilibit’s power. Lilibit ends up at a group home for unwanted children, damaged and near death. But she recovers and journeys to Kiva with the other children, bestowing upon them the stones that allow them to embrace their own powers, fight Syxx's minions, and save the earth.

The only other books I can think of are *[The Weirdstone of Brisingamen](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/694997.The_Weirdstone_of_Brisingamen)* by Alan Garner and *[The Stones of Green Knowe](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/377890.The_Stones_of_Green_Knowe)* by L. M. Boston ,but neither talk about listening to stones.
   Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much. I think this fits and I'll look into it.