# Book about a girl who can speak to/ understand stones

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I'm looking for a book about a girl who can speak to/ understand the feelings of stones.

What I remember about the book is that the girl is disfigured but as the story goes on she starts to heal. She meets a group of kids (either orphans or foster kids) who join her on her journey. Each of the kids seem to gain a special ability, I think by being chosen by a stone the girl thinks is compatible with them.

One of the kids is a girl who makes friends/ bonds with a member of a race of stone-like beings. Throughout the journey it becomes apparent that something or someone is after the main girl. I believe there was a guardian-like figure that occasionally appeared.

I had thought it was called "Stone Speaker" but can't find any results with that name. I believe it started out in a modern world setting. I read it in high school but it's been awhile.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you recall what the cover looked like?

Comment: Look at this post, it might  be about your book  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110557/please-help-me-remember-book-about-children-and-stones-that-possessed-power?rq=1

Comment: The book Alfred has linked is [Stone Voice Rising](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6314931-stone-voice-rising). That's reasonably similar to *Stone Speaker* and the plot does sound the same: *Lilibit can hear what the stones are whispering. She is meant to be the Earth’s new Stone Voice who will ultimately connect the planet with the universe.* If this is the book please let us know so we can mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: Might it be one of Tamora Pierce's books? In Street Magic we encounter Evvy, who turns out to be a stone-mage. In Battle Magic she encounters a stone creature, who decides to travel with her. They both appear again in Melting Stones. The only discrepancy is that she's not disfigured.